# How to make useable delete button to delete comments

Tags: javascript, html, css

I will like to know how to make my delete button work it has the id's of the comments and i just need to know how to get the button to delete the comments.
I would also like to make it so the user can only delete there comment not other users i would also like to know how to put a date on a comments.

```js
let slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
function up(){
window.scrollTo({top:0,behavior:'smooth'});
}
function dark(){
  
  var element = document.body;
   element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}

const Comments = [{user:'Nice guy',title:'Love this movie',id:'id1'},{user:'cool guy', title:'Best DBS movie ever',id:'id2'},{user:'Random guy' ,title: 'Borly was sooooooooo cooooool',id:'3'}];

render();

function addComments() {
  const textbox = document.getElementById('comment-title');
  const title = textbox.value;

  const userName = document.getElementById('user-name');
  const user = userName.value;

  const id = new Date().getTime();
  Comments.push({
    title:title,
    user:user,
    id:id
  });  
  
  render();
}

function deleteComment(event){
  const deleteButton = event.target;
  const idToDelete = deleteButton.id;

 Comments= Comments.filter(function(Comment){
    if (comment.id === idToDelete){
      return false
    }else{
      return true;
    }
    
  });
}

function render() {
  // reset our list
  document.getElementById('comment-List').innerHTML = '';

  Comments.forEach(function (comment) {
    const element = document.createElement('div');
    element.innerText = comment.user +': '+comment.title;
    element.style.textAlign = 'center'
    element.style.marginLeft='30%'
    element.style.marginRight='30%'
    element.style.padding='20px'

    element.style.fontFamily = 'Albert Sans, sans-serif';
    element.style.marginBottom = '20px'
    element.style.border='1px solid'
    element.style.borderRadius='20px'
    element.style.borderColor='blue'
    
    
    const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
    deleteButton.innerText = 'Delete';
    deleteButton.onclick = deleteComment;
    deleteButton.id = comment.id;
    element.appendChild(deleteButton);
    
    const commmentsList = document.getElementById('comment-List');
    commmentsList.appendChild(element);
    
    
  });
}
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #f0833a;

  }
  h1,h2,h3,h4,h5{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  }
  p{
    font-family: 'Albert Sans', sans-serif;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
  }
  .logo{
    width: 150px;
  }
    
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
padding: 16px;
background-color: #f0833a;
color: white;
font-size: 16px;
font-family: 'Albert Sans', sans-serif;
border: none;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
color: #f0833a;
font-family: 'Albert Sans', sans-serif;

padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #f0833a;}

* {box-sizing:border-box}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
max-width: 1000px;
position: relative;
margin: auto;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
width: auto;
margin-top: -22px;
padding: 16px;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 18px;
transition: 0.6s ease;
border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
right: 0;
border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}



/* Caption text */
.text {
color: #f0833a;
font-family: 'Albert Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
padding: 8px 12px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 8px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
color: #f0833a;
font-family: 'Albert Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
padding: 8px 12px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
cursor: pointer;
height: 15px;
width: 15px;
margin: 0 2px;
background-color: #bbb;
border-radius: 50%;
display: inline-block;
transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
background-color: #1dc40a;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
animation-name: fade;
animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes fade {
from {opacity: .4}
to {opacity: 1}
}
.center{
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 75%;

}
#footer{
margin-top: 20px;
background-color: black;
padding-bottom: 100px;
color: #f0833a;
}
.copyright{
float: right;

}
.made{
float: left;
}
.button{
background-color: #f0833a;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;  
color: white;
border-width: 0px;
height: 36px;
width: 74px;
font-size: 15px;
cursor: pointer;
transition: box-shadow 0.15s;
    color: 0.15s;
    
}
html {
scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
#nav{
min-height: 150px;
position: relative;

}


.dark-mode {
background-color: black;
color: white;
}
#add-comment{
background-color: black;
color: white;
border-width: 0px;
cursor: pointer;
vertical-align: top;
border-radius: 20px;
padding: 10px;
display: inline-block;
}
#add-comment:active{
opacity: 0.7;

}
#comment-title{
width: 250px;
border-radius: 20px;
border-width: 0px;
padding: 10px;
}
#user-name{
margin-left: 20%;
width: 250px;
border-radius: 20px;
border-width: 0px;
padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Rahim reviews</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Albert+Sans&family=Poppins:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">  

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="DBS.css">

</head>


<body>

<div id="nav" style="background-color: black">
  <img class="logo" src="pngwing.com.png" alt="">
  <div  class="dropdown">
    <button id="dropbtn" class="dropbtn">Home</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#overview">Overview</a>
        <a href="#review">Review</a>
        <a href="#footer">Footer</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="darkButton" style="position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; margin-left: 10%;" class="button" onclick="dark()">Dark mode</button>
</div>


<br>
<!-- Slideshow container -->
<h1 > Dragon Ball Super: Broly Review</h1>

<div class="slideshow-container">

  <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
    <img src="img1.jpg" style="width:100%;height: 500px;">
    <div class="text">Poster</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
    <img src="img2.jpg" style="width:100%;height: 500px;">
    <div class="text">Broly rage</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
    <img src="img3.jpg" style="width:100%;height: 500px;">
    <div class="text">Gogeta kamehameha</div>
  </div>


</div>
<br>

<!-- The dots/circles -->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <h2 id="overview">Overview</h2>
<p> <b>Ball Super: Broly</b> is essentially broken up into <b>two halves,</b>  the first of which covers Broly&apos;    s traumatic childhood and the end of the Saiyan race. What&apos;    s exciting here is that this is familiar territory
   that would make most Dragon Ball fans groan on any other occasion, yet Dragon Ball Super: Broly finds an<b> entertaining and efficient </b>way to condense all of that clutter. Broly takes this opportunity to rewrite 
   all of <b> Dragon Ball&apos; s</b> lingering plotlines and attempts to resolve several storylines that the series has hinted at in the past, like Frieza&apos;   s relationship with the Saiyan race, Bardock&apos;  s history, and the whole 
   Broly debacle.</p>
  
  </div>


<div>
  <iframe class="center" width="1000px" height="500px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/FHgm89hKpXU" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>  
   <h2 id="review">The review</h2>

   <p>Dragon Ball Super: Broly knows how much its fans want Gogeta and that there are nearly as many expectations behind Gogeta as there are with Broly. The film makes a meal out of the fusion sequence and doesn&apos;   t shy away from the technique&apos; s tricky learning curve and that the process can sometimes be full of imperfections. It basically takes everything that Fusion Reborn did with the character, but does it better. The super-powered character makes for the perfect climax to an already exciting film. During the whole trial and error section of the fusion process, Frieza successfully holds down the fort and gets to engage in an aggressive fight against Broly. It&apos;   s an effective way to add some variety to the movie&apos;   s battle scenes as well as a way to not lose any action during the more comedic fusion training sequence.
<br><br>
All of these fights are so entertaining because of the outstanding animation that&apos; s featured in the film. Sequences like baby Goku&apos;  s arrival on Earth, Vegeta and Goku&apos;   s first sparring match, and all of the Broly fights just look gorgeous. Dragon Ball Super has started to feature more engaging, impressive fight choreography throughout the end of its run, but the material here is on a whole other level. The camera weaves through and around battles without restriction, making it feel like the action never stops moving. It&apos; s really quite something.
<br><br>

<img class="center" src="fight.webp" alt="">
<br><br>
The animation, action, and character development are the film&apos; s priorities, but there&apos;   s still a lively sense of humor in the movie. Bulma and Frieza&apos;    s similar Dragon Ball wishes are not only the best potential wishes from the entire series but the strongest gags from the film, too. All of this is further punctuated by Norihito Sumitomo&apos;  s incredible score. Sumitomo&apos;  s work on Dragon Ball movies has only gotten better, but Broly&apos;    s score is definitely the strongest of the lot. The theme for Gogeta, “Gogeta Vs. Broly,” is not only a memorable track but it also repeatedly shouts Gogeta&apos;  s name out in celebration. The film&apos;   s major theme song by Daichi Miura, “Blizzard,” is grand stuff, too.
<br><br>
Dragon Ball Super: Broly is an absolute triumph on every front. It sets a new standard for what&apos;   s possible in Dragon Ball movies and not only does it present an effective new story, it fills in gaps in old ones, too. It&apos;   s packed with fan service for dedicated viewers, but still features plenty of surprises. It&apos;   s a pleasure to watch and it&apos;  s extremely gratifying to see that there&apos;  s still lots of life left in this franchise, even if it just becomes a film series.
</p>
</div>

<div class="center" >
<input  type="text" id="user-name" placeholder="Enter Username">
<input  id="comment-title" type="text" placeholder="Enter comment" />
    <button id="add-comment"  onclick="addComments()">Add Comment</button>
  </div>    
<div style="margin-top: 30px;" id="comment-List"></div>



<div id="footer">
  <div>
  <p class="made">Made by Guy</p>
</div>
<div>  
<p class="copyright">&copy;  Guy reviews· All rights reserved</p>
</div>
<div>
<button id="button" style="display: block;" class="button" class="center"  onclick="up()">Top</button>
</div>
</div>


<script src="DBS.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works, changed render(), deleteComment() and const -> let Comments

```js
let slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
function up(){
window.scrollTo({top:0,behavior:'smooth'});
}
function dark(){
  
  var element = document.body;
   element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}

let Comments = [{user:'Nice guy',title:'Love this movie',id:'id1'},{user:'cool guy', title:'Best DBS movie ever',id:'id2'},{user:'Random guy' ,title: 'Borly was sooooooooo cooooool',id:'3'}];

render();

function addComments() {
  const textbox = document.getElementById('comment-title');
  const title = textbox.value;

  const userName = document.getElementById('user-name');
  const user = userName.value;

  const id = new Date().getTime().toString();
  Comments.push({
    title:title,
    user:user,
    id:id
  });  
  
  render();
}

function deleteComment(event){
  const deleteButton = event.target;
  const idToDelete = deleteButton.id;

 Comments= Comments.filter(function(comment){
    if (comment.id === idToDelete){
      document.getElementById(comment.id).style.display = "none"
      return false
    }else{
      return true;
    }
    
  });
}

function render() {
  // reset our list
  document.getElementById('comment-List').innerHTML = '';

  Comments.forEach(function (comment) {
    const element = document.createElement('div');
    element.innerText = comment.user +': '+comment.title;
    element.style.textAlign = 'center'
    element.style.marginLeft='30%'
    element.style.marginRight='30%'
    element.style.padding='20px'

    element.style.fontFamily = 'Albert Sans, sans-serif';
    element.style.marginBottom = '20px'
    element.style.border='1px solid'
    element.style.borderRadius='20px'
    element.style.borderColor='blue'
    element.setAttribute("id", comment.id);
    
    
    const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
    deleteButton.innerText = 'Delete';
    deleteButton.onclick = deleteComment;
    deleteButton.id = comment.id;
    element.appendChild(deleteButton);
    
    const commmentsList = document.getElementById('comment-List');
    commmentsList.appendChild(element);
    
    
  });
}
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #f0833a;

  }
  h1,h2,h3,h4,h5{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  }
  p{
    font-family: 'Albert Sans', sans-serif;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
  }
  .logo{
    width: 150px;
  }
    
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
padding: 16px;
background-color: #f0833a;
color: white;
font-size: 16px;
font-family: 'Albert Sans', sans-serif;
border: none;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
color: #f0833a;
font-family: 'Albert Sans', sans-serif;

padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #f0833a;}

* {box-sizing:border-box}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
max-width: 1000px;
position: relative;
margin: auto;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
width: auto;
margin-top: -22px;
padding: 16px;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 18px;
transition: 0.6s ease;
border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
right: 0;
border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}



/* Caption text */
.text {
color: #f0833a;
font-family: 'Albert Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
padding: 8px 12px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 8px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
color: #f0833a;
font-family: 'Albert Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
padding: 8px 12px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
cursor: pointer;
height: 15px;
width: 15px;
margin: 0 2px;
background-color: #bbb;
border-radius: 50%;
display: inline-block;
transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
background-color: #1dc40a;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
animation-name: fade;
animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes fade {
from {opacity: .4}
to {opacity: 1}
}
.center{
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 75%;

}
#footer{
margin-top: 20px;
background-color: black;
padding-bottom: 100px;
color: #f0833a;
}
.copyright{
float: right;

}
.made{
float: left;
}
.button{
background-color: #f0833a;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;  
color: white;
border-width: 0px;
height: 36px;
width: 74px;
font-size: 15px;
cursor: pointer;
transition: box-shadow 0.15s;
    color: 0.15s;
    
}
html {
scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
#nav{
min-height: 150px;
position: relative;

}


.dark-mode {
background-color: black;
color: white;
}
#add-comment{
background-color: black;
color: white;
border-width: 0px;
cursor: pointer;
vertical-align: top;
border-radius: 20px;
padding: 10px;
display: inline-block;
}
#add-comment:active{
opacity: 0.7;

}
#comment-title{
width: 250px;
border-radius: 20px;
border-width: 0px;
padding: 10px;
}
#user-name{
margin-left: 20%;
width: 250px;
border-radius: 20px;
border-width: 0px;
padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Rahim reviews</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Albert+Sans&family=Poppins:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">  

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="DBS.css">

</head>


<body>

<div id="nav" style="background-color: black">
  <img class="logo" src="pngwing.com.png" alt="">
  <div  class="dropdown">
    <button id="dropbtn" class="dropbtn">Home</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#overview">Overview</a>
        <a href="#review">Review</a>
        <a href="#footer">Footer</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="darkButton" style="position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; margin-left: 10%;" class="button" onclick="dark()">Dark mode</button>
</div>


<br>
<!-- Slideshow container -->
<h1 > Dragon Ball Super: Broly Review</h1>

<div class="slideshow-container">

  <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
    <img src="img1.jpg" style="width:100%;height: 500px;">
    <div class="text">Poster</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
    <img src="img2.jpg" style="width:100%;height: 500px;">
    <div class="text">Broly rage</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
    <img src="img3.jpg" style="width:100%;height: 500px;">
    <div class="text">Gogeta kamehameha</div>
  </div>


</div>
<br>

<!-- The dots/circles -->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <h2 id="overview">Overview</h2>
<p> <b>Ball Super: Broly</b> is essentially broken up into <b>two halves,</b>  the first of which covers Broly&apos;    s traumatic childhood and the end of the Saiyan race. What&apos;    s exciting here is that this is familiar territory
   that would make most Dragon Ball fans groan on any other occasion, yet Dragon Ball Super: Broly finds an<b> entertaining and efficient </b>way to condense all of that clutter. Broly takes this opportunity to rewrite 
   all of <b> Dragon Ball&apos; s</b> lingering plotlines and attempts to resolve several storylines that the series has hinted at in the past, like Frieza&apos;   s relationship with the Saiyan race, Bardock&apos;  s history, and the whole 
   Broly debacle.</p>
  
  </div>


<div>
  <iframe class="center" width="1000px" height="500px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/FHgm89hKpXU" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>  
   <h2 id="review">The review</h2>

   <p>Dragon Ball Super: Broly knows how much its fans want Gogeta and that there are nearly as many expectations behind Gogeta as there are with Broly. The film makes a meal out of the fusion sequence and doesn&apos;   t shy away from the technique&apos; s tricky learning curve and that the process can sometimes be full of imperfections. It basically takes everything that Fusion Reborn did with the character, but does it better. The super-powered character makes for the perfect climax to an already exciting film. During the whole trial and error section of the fusion process, Frieza successfully holds down the fort and gets to engage in an aggressive fight against Broly. It&apos;   s an effective way to add some variety to the movie&apos;   s battle scenes as well as a way to not lose any action during the more comedic fusion training sequence.
<br><br>
All of these fights are so entertaining because of the outstanding animation that&apos; s featured in the film. Sequences like baby Goku&apos;  s arrival on Earth, Vegeta and Goku&apos;   s first sparring match, and all of the Broly fights just look gorgeous. Dragon Ball Super has started to feature more engaging, impressive fight choreography throughout the end of its run, but the material here is on a whole other level. The camera weaves through and around battles without restriction, making it feel like the action never stops moving. It&apos; s really quite something.
<br><br>

<img class="center" src="fight.webp" alt="">
<br><br>
The animation, action, and character development are the film&apos; s priorities, but there&apos;   s still a lively sense of humor in the movie. Bulma and Frieza&apos;    s similar Dragon Ball wishes are not only the best potential wishes from the entire series but the strongest gags from the film, too. All of this is further punctuated by Norihito Sumitomo&apos;  s incredible score. Sumitomo&apos;  s work on Dragon Ball movies has only gotten better, but Broly&apos;    s score is definitely the strongest of the lot. The theme for Gogeta, “Gogeta Vs. Broly,” is not only a memorable track but it also repeatedly shouts Gogeta&apos;  s name out in celebration. The film&apos;   s major theme song by Daichi Miura, “Blizzard,” is grand stuff, too.
<br><br>
Dragon Ball Super: Broly is an absolute triumph on every front. It sets a new standard for what&apos;   s possible in Dragon Ball movies and not only does it present an effective new story, it fills in gaps in old ones, too. It&apos;   s packed with fan service for dedicated viewers, but still features plenty of surprises. It&apos;   s a pleasure to watch and it&apos;  s extremely gratifying to see that there&apos;  s still lots of life left in this franchise, even if it just becomes a film series.
</p>
</div>

<div class="center" >
<input  type="text" id="user-name" placeholder="Enter Username">
<input  id="comment-title" type="text" placeholder="Enter comment" />
    <button id="add-comment"  onclick="addComments()">Add Comment</button>
  </div>    
<div style="margin-top: 30px;" id="comment-List"></div>



<div id="footer">
  <div>
  <p class="made">Made by Guy</p>
</div>
<div>  
<p class="copyright">&copy;  Guy reviews· All rights reserved</p>
</div>
<div>
<button id="button" style="display: block;" class="button" class="center"  onclick="up()">Top</button>
</div>
</div>


<script src="DBS.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you make it so the user can only delete the comments that they have made. It doesn't delete the new comments that the user has made.

Comment: Didn't see that will check

Comment: Okay it's working now, converted id date to string